# TextBox.Focus() does not work in interface in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, interface

I have set `textbox.Focus()` on iterface. When i come to page very first time it works but after navigate to other page when again come to same page where i set interface my textbox.Focus() does not work.

I simply use this in the interface:

```
textbox.Text = string.Empty;
textbox.Focus();
```

Also it takes old value. Suppose if i want to set string.empty in textbox it only works for first time but not second time.

Please tell me what could be the solution.

Thanks,
Nishant

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the same in OnNavigatedTo event of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    textbox.Text = "";
    textbox.Focus();
}
```